# Is it good for the body to do some stretching at random times during the day?

Tags: stretching

It happens to me that when I go for a run, then my body does not really feel like stretching. Then, after an hour or so, I can do that and it relaxes me a lot.

Also, I may be somewhere outside during the day and have some time to 'kill': waiting for the bus, watching to my kids, etc. Those are kind of boring moments of the day where I feel like stretching, and I do it. Mostly, I stretch my legs muscles, such as quadriceps, calf, and others.

For this, I wonder: is it good for the muscles to stretch them randomly, from time to time? Do this increase the flexibility over time? Is there any risk in doing so?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to stretch throughout the day, that's a great idea and a great way to avoid injury, but be advised on what kind of stretching your doing before physical activity

Before doing any intense work, its good to do quick stretches without long holds. When you do very long stretches, like staying in a split, or stretches where you sit down, the muscles relax and loosen, only to get shocked by the intense workout.

Thenx has a great video on this https://youtu.be/4PZlJdpF73s
I highly recommend checking it out